# Display array of arrays in view from controller codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, view, display

I am trying to display an array or arrays in my view and I am having difficulties on how to do it, so any help will be  much appreciated :)

My array of arrays in the model:

```
$user = array();
...
$user[$id] = array(
            'id' => $userId[$id],
            'match' => $percentage
        );
return array('userInfo' => $user);
```

that stores info from some users. I am passing it to the controller and from there to the view where I want to display the information in $user array. In the array can be one or many users.

here is my controller:

```
$result = $this->model->getUserDetails();

$this->load->view('view', array('user' => $result);
```

in the view I want to print the info but I do not know how to do it since I have never worked with arrays of arrays and I am a bit confused.

here is the view:

```
<?php foreach ($user['userInfo'] as $index => $value) {
    echo $value[$index]['id'].' '.$value[$index]['match'];
?>
```

if I do it this way

or

```
echo $value['id'];
```

or

```
echo $index['id'];
```

the view displays nothing or doesn't like the 'id' index

this is what I have for

```
var_dump($result); 

array(1) { ["result"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { 
["id"]=> string(2) "55" 
["fname"]=> string(6) "Dan" ["lname"]=> string(5) "Re" 
["email"]=> string(18) "d@gmail.com" ["username"]=> string(6) "dan"    
["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["DOB"]=> string(10) "1990-07-13" 
["profile_image"]=> string(8) "dan.jpg" 
["short_des"]=> string(147) "I love singing and playing music" 
["pwd"]=> string(4) "dan" ["confirm_pwd"]=> string(4) "dan" } } }
```

meaning that there is one user to be displayed

Pls do help as I am very confused.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add the contents of `var_dump($result);` to your question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the result for `var_dump($result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are expecting `$this->model->getUserDetails()` to return a single array with a users details. It is in fact returning the array you care about nested within several other arrays.

Change this line:

```
$this->load->view('view', array('user' => $result);
```

To:

```
$this->load->view('view', array('user' => $result['result'][0]);
```

And I believe your problem will be solved.

Albeit that line doesn't look so pretty! If you intended your `getUserDetails()` function to return just a single array about a single user (presumably the current one logged in) then I would recommend changing the return value of that function.

Comment: the thing is that the array $result can hold one or many users, depending on the outcome of the function in model, so I want it to return as many as the function returns, not just one; will the new line work with many users returned?

Comment: @Nynaeve The problem then would be how you would define "work." The line will compile and the page will render if you change it to that. The issue becomes the `[0]` in the line above. If you keep that `[0]` hard coded, `$user` will always be whatever row happened to be returned first from the query in the `getUserDetails()` function.